# wrap apache virtual host around another (proxy)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Let's say i have site www.x.com in english, then www.x.de in german, and what I want to do is point all the variants at primary virtual host with some hidden parameter like ?lang=de but also with priority of some files like if exists logo on german version use german logo otherwise the file in x.com virtual host.

So far I had multiple hostings that works as above except virtual hosts are not used, and that the mutation sites use proxy script to call the main page, but for example if image exists on the mutation hosting it is used from it, otherwise from proxy.

As new solution I want to drop the proxy script a multiple hostings thing and use apache virtual hosts on VPS.

I know it should be (?) possible to point multiple aliases or multiple domains at one folder (virtual host) on the server (btw how to pass the lang url parameter?) but what is the question is:

Is it possible to have Virtual Host A, then Virtual Host B which in fact uses the virtual Host A, but if some requested file exists in the Virtual Host B folder it is used (as the mentioned logo file)?

Second solution is to point all domains at one virtual host and change somehow the site scripts to use some image sub folder for specific language but I wonder if the previous thing is possible.

Answer (score 1):

With `mod_rewrite` you should be able to get the parameter, even with only one `VirtualHost`. But keep in mind that you'll run into issues in SSL `VirtualHosts` if not using a SAN certificate. Otherwise, you can use two separate `VirtualHosts` with the apropiate certificate. The logo part *might* work too, but it may be too much of a burden to maintain.

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www.example.de

RewriteEngine On

# When using two VHosts you don't need this Cond or the [C] flag
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.de
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1?lang=de [C]

RewriteCond "$1-de\.jpg" -f
RewriteRule ^(logo).jpg$ logo-de.jpg
```

Comment: hi thx for reply. so i am thinking either one VH with multiple aliases (but then there is the SSL issue), or what about multiple VH each with own SSL certificate but all same document root? (and then remains to fix the own files)

Comment: Either of them should work, but with multiple VHost you won't have to renew expensive SAN certificates when adding domains.